# Google maps not drawing the map on localhost

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Am trying to first get my current co-ordinates using navigator.geolocation and then use the latitude and longitude to draw the map.

But it's not showing the map, just blank white screen.

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
        html{height: 100%}
        body{height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0}
        #map-canvas{height: 100%}
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
function getLocation()
{
    if (navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
    else
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser");
}
function showPosition(position)
{
    coord = {};
    coord.lat = position.coords.latitude;
    coord.longi = position.coords.longitude;
    initialize(coord);
}

function initialize(coord) {
  var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
  var map_options = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(coord.lat, coord.longi),
    zoom:8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', getLocation);


</script>
<body>
<div id="map_canvas" data-role="page"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you sure that you run this on localhost(a local webserver) and not on the local filesystem? Which browser do you use?

Comment: python -m http.server 80 pretty sure!

Comment: I am using chrome browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to post this http://jsfiddle.net/n5jqpo9u/1/ and say I don't see a problem in your code and mine works...

and right before I press the post button, I realized, you used `map-canvas` rather than `map_canvas` for your css...

`-` and `_`  :(

and by the way, you can not get location when you run it as a file using chrome. Also if the operation timed out and or your app has no permission for location, it will display a white page too. and so you should add error handling like this:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation_error

Comment: OH MY GOD! Dude you have hawk eye!